# How to add library to C++ Project using homebrew, cMake and, cLion

Tags: c++, cmake, homebrew, clion

I am really new to C++ and I am a bit confused.

I am trying to add this lib to my project (https://github.com/mrtazz/restclient-cpp).
I have installed it using Homebrew

```
brew tap mrtazz/oss
brew install restclient-cpp
```

then I tried adding the library to my CMakeLists by including and linking the Homebrew install directories.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(POS)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(/usr/local/include)
link_directories(/usr/local/lib)

add_library(
        restclient-cpp STATIC
        connection.h
        helpers.h
        restclient.h
        version.h
)

add_executable(POS main.cpp program.cpp program.h programs/find.cpp programs/find.h tools/db.cpp tools/db.h)

target_link_libraries(POS PUBLIC restclient-cpp)
```

then I get this error...

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

    connection.h

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_library):
  No SOURCES given to target: restclient-cpp
```

I know something is wrong with the directories but I just cannot figure it out, I would greatly appreciate as much information as possible. I'm just trying to have some fun with this and I cannot figure out why I cannot add this simple library to my build.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add header files to the `add_library` command. Those files need to be in a directory that you include via `include_directory`. You also should not put header files into the `add_executable` command.

To link an existing library you can call `target_link_libraries`.

example:

```
include_directories(${MY_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(main source.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main extlib)
```

It's probably best to find a [simple CMake setup](http://derekmolloy.ie/hello-world-introductions-to-cmake) and try to use it as template.

Comment: I removed the add_library line, Now the `target_link_libraries` works. This is because the library I am trying to add has already been compiled? I will do more research on why this is working now but thank you.

Comment: Yes, `add_library` is used to generate a library - just like `add_executable`.